# How to avoid data racing when using the SavedStateHandle API in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

To avoid data loss on process termination, I use the SavedStateHandle API in my view models. Nevertheless, it appears that data races may occur if multiple threads attempt to modify the data contained in the SavedStateHandle class instance. In my example here, reading the view state and updating it is not atomic. I tried to simulate data race, but nothing really happened.

I have a class that represents a view state:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class ExampleViewState(
  val title: String = "",
  val description: String = "",
  ...
) : Parcelable
```

And, view model that should hold the view related states on configuration changes:

```kotlin
private const val VIEW_STATE = "view_state"

@HiltViewModel
internal class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val repository: SomeRepository,
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

  val viewStateFlow = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(VIEW_STATE, ExampleViewState())

  fun onTitleChanged(newTitle: String) {
    val viewState = viewStateFlow.value
    savedStateHandle[VIEW_STATE] = viewState.copy(title = newTitle)
  }

  fun onDescriptionChanged(newDescription: String) { ... }

  init {
    initializeData()
  }

  private fun initializeData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val someData = repository.fetchData(...)
    val viewState = viewStateFlow.value
    savedStateHandle[VIEW_STATE] = viewState.copy(
      title = someData.title,
      description = someData.description,
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

I came across with this solution:

```kotlin
private inline fun updateViewState(update: (ExampleViewState) -> ExampleViewState) {
   synchronized(viewStateFlow) {
       savedStateHandle[VIEW_STATE] = update(viewStateFlow.value)
   }
}
```

Here I'm putting a synchronized block around the code that updates the view state.
But problem with this approach if I have multiple state flow instances, I have to create that many update functions